# Cifrar-Encriptar contraseña o cadena de conexion en App.config

Tags: c#

requiero proteger mis datos de conexión, actualmente están expuestos en el app.config que genera el entityframework ejemplo:

```
<add name="MiConexion" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatosEntityFramework.ModelSistema.csdl|res://*/DatosEntityFramework.ModelSistema.ssdl|res://*/DatosEntityFramework.ModelSistema.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LOCALHOST;initial catalog=SISTEMA; persist security info=True;user id=usuario;password=123456;               MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hechar un vistazo a [este articulo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows) (está en inglés). Ahi te explican muy detalladamente como utilizar `System.Configuration.SectionInformation.ProtectSection`.

Utilizando `ProtectSection` conseguirás que un usuario medio no tenga acceso a la información que encriptes, pero ten en cuenta que otro programador podría copiar tu fichero .config usarlo en una aplicación propia desde la que llamar `UnProtectSection()` y obtener asi acceso a todo lo encriptado.